# Black screen after modifying index.js

Tags: react-native

I am following a tutorial online to learn how to use React.

The instructor made me create a project called `albums` and modify the content of `index.js`, however I get a black screen on the ios simulator.

What I did (following the instructor's details):

1) Create a new project `react-native init-albums`

2) Enter the project directory with   `cd albums`

3) Run `react-native run-ios`

4) I can see on the simulator screen what is inside the file App.js (The initial screen of - I assume - any new React Native project). 
*Press Cmd+R to reload*, *Cmd+D or shake for dev menu* etc.

5) Delete the content inside `index.js` and replace it with:

```
import React from "react";
import { AppRegistry, Text } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
 return <Text>Some Text</Text>;
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent("albums", () => App);
```

It should appear *Some Text* on the top left of the simulator BUT it does not. The screen is black.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a background color for you application. You should also import `View` from react-native

```
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
 return (
   <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', flex:1}}>
     <Text>Some Text</Text>
   </View>
  );
};
```

The reason that it is black is because the in the `AppDelegate.m` the rootView backgroundColor has been changed in version `0.58.0`

In prior versions it was

```
rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
```

It is now the following in `0.58.+`

```
rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: Thanks! The tutorial did not specify it. I guess I have also to import `View` like this: `import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from "react-native";`

Comment: Unfortunately tutorials go out of date fairly quickly as `react-native` development moves quite fast. Yes you will have to import the View, I was just in the process of updating my post with that