# React Navigation v3 BottomTabNavigator Black Screen on iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm testing out React Navigation's BottomTabNavigator but after running it in ios simulator I'm getting a black screen.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create react native project `react-native init Example`
2. Install and link react-navigation and deps `npm install --save react-navigation react-native-gesture-handler && react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`
3. Replace the App.js content with:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

4. Then run in simulator `react-native run-ios`

[image: result]

I've also tried deleting node_modules, build folders & cleaning npm cache & simulator contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Black screen after modifying index.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654224/black-screen-after-modifying-index-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't get an error, it might just be because you didn't set a background color on your `<View>` tags.

Try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

        class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
          render() {
            return (
              <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor:'#fff' }}>
                <Text>Home!</Text>
              </View>
            );
          }
        }

        class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
          render() {
            return (
              <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor:'#fff' }}>
                <Text>Settings!</Text>
              </View>
            );
          }
        }

    const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
      Home: HomeScreen,
      Settings: SettingsScreen,
    });

    export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Hope this helps.